# Display Yoast meta-description `wpseo_desc` within loop of categories and fail silently if no data is set

Tags: php, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I want to output the Yoast SEO category meta-description within a custom loop. Current code (below) works if there is a meta-description present. However, if no category meta-description is set it breaks.

Is there a better way to write this so that it fails silently if no meta-description is set

```
<?php 
$popular_topics = get_field('popular_topics');
if( $popular_topics ):
      foreach( $popular_topics as $topic ): 
        $id    = $topic->term_id;
        $meta  = get_option( 'wpseo_taxonomy_meta' );
        $meta_desc   = $meta['category'][$id]['wpseo_desc'];
        ?>
          <p class="my-paragraph">
            <?php echo esc_html( $meta_desc ); ?>
          </p>
      <?php endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

Edit, wrapped in a simple `!empty` if statement

```
if(!empty( $meta['category'][$id]['wpseo_desc'] )) {
 echo $meta['category'][$id]['wpseo_desc'];
}
else {
 echo "Meta not present";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap in a `!empty` statement

```
if(!empty( $meta['category'][$id]['wpseo_desc'] )) {
 echo $meta['category'][$id]['wpseo_desc'];
}
else {
 echo "Meta not present";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if `$meta` and `$meta_desc` exist. If not, don't echo anything.

```
$popular_topics = get_field('popular_topics');

if ( $popular_topics ) : 

    foreach ( $popular_topics as $topic ) : 

        $id = $topic->term_id;
        $meta = get_option('wpseo_taxonomy_meta');

        if ( $id && ( $meta && !empty($meta) ) ) : 

            $meta_desc = $meta['category'][$id]['wpseo_desc'];

            if ( $meta_desc ) : ?>

                <p class="my-paragraph">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $meta_desc ); ?>
                </p>

                <?php

            endif;

        endif;

    endforeach;

endif;
```

Comment: Unfortunately even with this configuration if the meta_desc is empty the line ` $meta_desc = $meta['category'][$id]['wpseo_desc'];` causes error "Notice: Undefined offset"

Comment: You can check if your $meta variable is not empty. See edited code.